# Disassembly of raw binary of AARCH64 using Ghidra not complete

Tags: disassembly, ghidra, binary, aarch64

I am trying to disassemble a raw binary with **AARCH64:LE:64:v8A​:default** (as per below mentioned specs).

> Architecture: aarch64
> CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
> Byte Order: Little Endian
> CPU(s): 8
> On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
> Vendor ID: Nvidia
> Model: 0
> Model name: ARMv8 Processor rev 0 (v8l)
> Compiler - aarch64-gnu-linux GCC compiler

Here are the steps I followed:

1. After importing the bin file, I ran auto analysis with default options selected.
2. Selected the code (ctrl+A) then pressed d (for manual disassembly).

This ran for around 3 hrs and the disassembled code that it generated still had many bytes as "??". Also, when I try to generate the code flow, it runs into heap memory issue (currently heap size set to 4GB).

[image: typical output and errors]

Is there any step that I am missing out? Or if anyone can help me what else I can try further?

Comment: (Maybe) not enough memory?

Comment: Your step 2 is the wrong approach.  you can't just do that and expect great results, not everything is an instruction (even if they can decode as instructions)

Comment: Are you sure you have the right endianness? 90% of the time when I disassemble code and have unidentified instructions, it's because I used the wrong endianness.

Comment: Are you sure it’s actually Aarch64?

Comment: @mumbel thanks for replying. Does that mean the bytes that have not been disassembled are not instructions and need to be handled differently? How can that be done?

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook yes, endianness is correct. But just to try out, I have run the analysis again with big endian. I will get back with the results when its done.

Comment: yes @IgorSkochinsky its the correct architecture.